# jQuery event on form field

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I've a change event in a jQuery script which fails to fire but I cannot understand what is wrong/missing (there is also a datepicker and timepicker which is working ok).  Any advice - greatly welcomed.

e.g.

**jquery**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    $("#to_place").change(function () {         <==
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");    <== not working?
    });
    
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
        inline: true
    });

    $('.bfh-timepicker').timepicki({
                    show_meridian:false,
                    min_hour_value:0,
                    max_hour_value:23,
                    step_size_minutes:5,
                    overflow_minutes:true,
                    increase_direction:'up',
                    disable_keyboard_mobile: false});   
});

**HTML**
```

```html
                <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    <label for="to">To</label>
                    <input placeholder="to" class="form-control" name="to_place" type="text">
                    
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`to_place` is name of the input field so try this:

```
 $("input[name='to_place']").change(function () {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your change event is binding to an element with the ID 'to_place' so add an ID to the input field. e.g.

```
...
<input placeholder="to" class="form-control" id="to_place" name="to_place" type="text">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#to_place") part of the code is searching for an element with id="to_place" that is not found on your snippet. Adding this to your input element should be enough to trigger the change event.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery selector "#to_place" is an ID selector, but you didn't set the ID for the text box.
You can use "input[name=to_place]" instead of that.
Or you can just add the ID attribute to the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below answer, it will work fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#to_place").change(function () {    
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box from change function!!");
    });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
        <label for="to">To</label>
        <input placeholder="to" class="form-control" name="to_place" type="text" id="to_place" />
 </div>
```